# BarCode detection in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want to implement read/scan bar code in my iPhone application. I would like to know how to implement it into our iPhone app and also some links and example code and apps to check out how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our free app pic2shop as an external barcode scanner (from a web page or from another app).  Here is a demo and detailed info: http://www.pic2shop.com/developers.html

It works even on non-autofocus devices (iPad2, iPod Touch, iPhone 3G and many Android phones).