# Barcode read / scan can be done in the iPhone application...?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BarCode detection in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242291/barcode-detection-in-iphone)

I am interested to give the functionality of barcode scan / read in my iphone application.

How can I be able to implement read/scan bar code in my iphone application.

I also would like to know how to implement it into the iphone application.

If possible suggest me the links and example source code and applications to understand how it works.

I want to generate the barcode dynamically...is i possible...if yes then suggest me how it can be generated..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read barcodes: Zbar, ZXing, Redlaser
To Generate Barcodes: https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes

If you look up their websites you can download their sample application as well.